# Function $f$ from $[0,\infty)$ such that is limit at infinity equals zero and it's values greater than zero must decrease somewhere

Tags: calculus, limits

I got this question:

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $ \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$
and for all $x \in [0,\infty), f(x)>0$ then there exist a number $M>0$ such that $f$ is monotonically decreasing on the interval $[M, \infty)$

Is this statement true or false?
From an intuitive point of view it sounds true but I tried to prove it but failed so far.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not true. Draw a graph of $f(x) := \frac{1}{1+x}$ and add a sinusoidal oscilliation of decreasing amplitude (to ensure that the function remains positive everywhere).

Comment: You mean that we can create a positive function that will increase and decrease infinitely and still will approche 0 at infinity?

Comment: Yes indeed. See LinAlgMan's answer for a slightly different but complete version of what I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not assume continuity the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac2x, & \text{ if }  x \in \mathbb N\\ \frac1x, & \text{ elsewhere }  \end{cases}$$ serves as a counterexample. This functions has jumps in every integer (so that monotonicity is violated), however these jumps also converge to zero.

Comment: Nice counter example. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is falso. Consider the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{ |\sin(x)| }{1+x } $$
Then 
$$ 0 \le \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+x} = 0 $$
but $f(x)$ is never monotonic.